# Stopping frequency drift NTX2B FM transmitter

Tags: microcontroller, rf

I'm following the instructions [here](https://ukhas.org.uk/guides:linkingarduinotontx2) to connect an NTX2B ([datasheet](http://www.radiometrix.com/content/ntx2)) to a Raspberry Pi Pico.

I have the circuit and code working correctly, however I'm having an issue with the frequency drifting.
The carrier remains stable, it is the modulating frequency that's the issue.

This frequency is determined by the voltage applied to the TXN pin on the NTX2B (VCO.) This is controlled by a voltage divider (resistors) and GPIO on the Raspberry Pi. I'm assuming thermal effects on the resistors are negligible and the Raspberry Pi GPIO voltage is stable

The circuit is currently assembled on stripboard, and solder quality is ok. No obvious shorts.

I do not currently have an antenna attached, ruling this as an issue out given the carrier is stable, and not seeing harmonics in waterfall chart.

Changing power supply has made no difference.

Anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Define test results and requirements with errors noticed. This requires measurements of Vin and Fout and temperature of case or hottest lead.

Comment: Spec= 2kHz/V +/-16.7% over temp on VCXO up to 60’C for 0 to 3V in

Comment: They do not seem to have an offset spec for the VCXO, so if you are getting drift, I would not follow the guide which is sub-optimal and bias to 1.5V and AC couple a data baseband modulation that does not rely on DC like MFM, biPhase or QPSK, and use as much of the 3V swing that does not interfere with adjacent channels. That guide simply biased to 2.5V and very small deviation ratio